# Space wastage in b-tree interior page sqllite

Tags: sqlite, database-design

In interior page since only keys and pointer is stored no value is stored, when compared to leaf page which also contains full key with value, space occupied in interior page would be much less even when full K keys are there. What happens to that left over space in interior Page. How will it be utilized?
I assume left over space would be huge.

Comment: As is normal for b-trees with fixed size pages/nodes, unused space in a page is used when having to add new key and pointer to a new child page.

Comment: https://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#b_tree_pages has details